# Qt: Widgets overlap in scrollarea

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget, scrollview

So I have a program that reads parameters from a file and builds an UI around those parameters. The parameters need some controls etc so I made a widget for that:
[image: Widget]

It will be added X amount of times depending of the X amount parameters in the file. If the amount of parameters is small enough the program looks fine like so:
[image: program normal]

However, if there are too much parameters they will overlap even though they are placed in a scrollarea:
[image: program normal overlap]

It gets even worse when I re-size the window:
[image: program resized overlap]

I create the layout with the following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_treeView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    //user clicked category in treeview.
    int returnedrow = index.row();
    int returnedcol = index.column();
    returnedcol = returnedcol;
    const QAbstractItemModel * model = index.model();
    QVariant vt = model->data(model->index(index.row(), returnedcol, index.parent()), Qt::DisplayRole);
    QString compare = vt.toString();
    size_t maxsizearr = returnedrow;
    QWidget *box = new QWidget();
    QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout(box);
    int row = 0,column =0;

    for(size_t k=0;k<ipdb.size();++k) //Find out which category was clicked and then make GUI
    {
        if(maxsizearr<ipdb[k].subip.size())
        {
            if(  ipdb[k].subip[returnedrow].compare(compare.toStdString()) == 0)//category found, build GUI
            {
                //ui->mainlabel->setText("found");
                int size = vprParam_GetSize(database[k].instance[returnedrow]); //Number of parameters in category
                for(int i=0; i<size;++i)
                {
                    QString name = vprParam_GetNameById(database[k].instance[returnedrow],i);
                    int min = vprParam_GetRangeMinByName(database[k].instance[returnedrow],name.toStdString().c_str());
                    int max = vprParam_GetRangeMaxByName(database[k].instance[returnedrow],name.toStdString().c_str());
                    int value = vprParam_GetByName(database[k].instance[returnedrow],name.toStdString().c_str());
                    ParamBlock *widget = new ParamBlock();
                    widget->changeTitle(name);
                    widget->changeMin(min);
                    widget->changeMax(max);
                    widget->setValue(value);
                    grid->addWidget(widget,row,column);
                    ++row;
                    if(row>14)
                    {
                        row=0;
                        ++column;
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (row<14&&row>0) //add empty widgets to make the spacing equal in all catogeries
    {
        for(int b = row; b<=14;++b)
        {
            QWidget *filler = new QWidget();
            grid->addWidget(filler,b,column);
        }
    }
    ui->scrollArea->setWidget(box);
}
```

Code of ParamBlock.cpp:

```
#include "paramblock.h"
#include "ui_paramblock.h"

ParamBlock::ParamBlock(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ParamBlock)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ParamBlock::~ParamBlock()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ParamBlock::changeTitle(QString X)
{
    ui->groupBox->setTitle(X);
}

void ParamBlock::changeMin(int X)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(X));
    ui->horizontalSlider->setMinimum(X);
}

void ParamBlock::changeMax(int X)
{
    ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(X));
    ui->horizontalSlider->setMaximum(X);
}

void ParamBlock::setValue(int X)
{
    ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(X);
    ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(X));
}


void ParamBlock::on_lineEdit_textEdited(const QString &arg1)
{

    if((arg1.toInt())>(ui->horizontalSlider->maximum()))
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(ui->horizontalSlider->maximum()));
        ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(ui->horizontalSlider->maximum());
    }
    else if((arg1.toInt())<(ui->horizontalSlider->minimum()))
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(ui->horizontalSlider->minimum()));
        ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(ui->horizontalSlider->minimum());
    }
    else
        ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(arg1.toInt());

}

void ParamBlock::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(value));
}
```

ParamBlock.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>ParamBlock</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="ParamBlock">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>326</width>
    <height>53</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QToolTip
{
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color: #ffa02f;
     padding: 1px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     opacity: 100;
}

QWidget
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #323232;
}

QWidget:item:hover
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1#d7801a);
    color: #000000;
}

QWidget:item:selected
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
}

QMenuBar::item
{
    background: transparent;
}

QMenuBar::item:selected
{
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #ffaa00;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed
{
    background: #444;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: QLinearGradient(
        x1:0, y1:0,
        x2:0, y2:1,
        stop:1 #212121,
        stop:0.4 #343434/*,
        stop:0.2 #343434,
        stop:0.1 #ffaa00*/
    );
    margin-bottom:-1px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}

QMenu
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

QMenu::item
{
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 20px;
}

QMenu::item:selected
{
    color: #000000;
}

QWidget:disabled
{
    color: #404040;
    background-color: #323232;
}

QAbstractItemView
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #4d4d4d, stop: 0.1 #646464, stop: 1 #5d5d5d);
}

QWidget:focus
{
    /*border: 2px solid QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);*/
}

QLineEdit
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #4d4d4d, stop: 0 #646464, stop: 1 #5d5d5d);
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
    border-radius: 5;
}

QPushButton
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #565656, stop: 0.1 #525252, stop: 0.5 #4e4e4e, stop: 0.9 #4a4a4a, stop: 1 #464646);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #1e1e1e;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

QPushButton:pressed
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #2d2d2d, stop: 0.1 #2b2b2b, stop: 0.5 #292929, stop: 0.9 #282828, stop: 1 #252525);
}

QComboBox
{
    selection-background-color: #ffaa00;
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #565656, stop: 0.1 #525252, stop: 0.5 #4e4e4e, stop: 0.9 #4a4a4a, stop: 1 #464646);
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
    border-radius: 5;
}

QComboBox:hover,QPushButton:hover
{
    border: 2px solid QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
}


QComboBox:on
{
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #2d2d2d, stop: 0.1 #2b2b2b, stop: 0.5 #292929, stop: 0.9 #282828, stop: 1 #252525);
    selection-background-color: #ffaa00;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    selection-background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
}

QComboBox::drop-down
{
     subcontrol-origin: padding;
     subcontrol-position: top right;
     width: 15px;

     border-left-width: 0px;
     border-left-color: darkgray;
     border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
     border-top-right-radius: 3px; /* same radius as the QComboBox */
     border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 }

QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    image: url(:/down_arrow.png);
}


QGroupBox:focus
{
border: 2px solid QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
}

QTextEdit:focus
{
    border: 2px solid QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
}

QScrollBar:horizontal {
     border: 1px solid #222222;
     background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0.0 #121212, stop: 0.2 #282828, stop: 1 #484848);
     height: 7px;
     margin: 0px 16px 0 16px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal
{
      background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 0.5 #d7801a, stop: 1 #ffa02f);
      min-height: 20px;
      border-radius: 2px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
      border: 1px solid #1b1b19;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
      width: 14px;
      subcontrol-position: right;
      subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
      border: 1px solid #1b1b19;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
      width: 14px;
     subcontrol-position: left;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::left-arrow:horizontal
{
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      background: white;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
{
      background: none;
}

QScrollBar:vertical
{
      background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, stop: 0.0 #121212, stop: 0.2 #282828, stop: 1 #484848);
      width: 7px;
      margin: 16px 0 16px 0;
      border: 1px solid #222222;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical
{
      background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 0.5 #d7801a, stop: 1 #ffa02f);
      min-height: 20px;
      border-radius: 2px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
{
      border: 1px solid #1b1b19;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
      height: 14px;
      subcontrol-position: bottom;
      subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
{
      border: 1px solid #1b1b19;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #d7801a, stop: 1 #ffa02f);
      height: 14px;
      subcontrol-position: top;
      subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
{
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      background: white;
}


QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
{
      background: none;
}

QTextEdit
{
    background-color: #242424;
}

QPlainTextEdit
{
    background-color: #242424;
}

QHeaderView::section
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #616161, stop: 0.5 #505050, stop: 0.6 #434343, stop:1 #656565);
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}

QCheckBox:disabled
{
color: #414141;
}

QDockWidget::title
{
    text-align: center;
    spacing: 3px; /* spacing between items in the tool bar */
    background-color: QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #323232, stop: 0.5 #242424, stop:1 #323232);
}

QDockWidget::close-button, QDockWidget::float-button
{
    text-align: center;
    spacing: 1px; /* spacing between items in the tool bar */
    background-color: QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #323232, stop: 0.5 #242424, stop:1 #323232);
}

QDockWidget::close-button:hover, QDockWidget::float-button:hover
{
    background: #242424;
}

QDockWidget::close-button:pressed, QDockWidget::float-button:pressed
{
    padding: 1px -1px -1px 1px;
}

QMainWindow::separator
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #161616, stop: 0.5 #151515, stop: 0.6 #212121, stop:1 #343434);
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
    spacing: 3px; /* spacing between items in the tool bar */
}

QMainWindow::separator:hover
{

    background-color: QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #d7801a, stop:0.5 #b56c17 stop:1 #ffa02f);
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
    spacing: 3px; /* spacing between items in the tool bar */
}

QToolBar::handle
{
     spacing: 3px; /* spacing between items in the tool bar */
    background: url(:/images/handle.png);
}

QMenu::separator
{
    height: 2px;
    background-color: QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #161616, stop: 0.5 #151515, stop: 0.6 #212121, stop:1 #343434);
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

QProgressBar
{
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

QProgressBar::chunk
{
    background-color: #d7801a;
    width: 2.15px;
    margin: 0.5px;
}

QTabBar::tab {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    background-color: #323232;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-right: -1px;
}

QTabWidget::pane {
    border: 1px solid #444;
    top: 1px;
}

QTabBar::tab:last
{
    margin-right: 0; /* the last selected tab has nothing to overlap with on the right */
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

QTabBar::tab:first:!selected
{
 margin-left: 0px; /* the last selected tab has nothing to overlap with on the right */


    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

QTabBar::tab:!selected
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    margin-top: 3px;
    background-color: QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:1 #212121, stop:.4 #343434);
}

QTabBar::tab:selected
{
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

QTabBar::tab:!selected:hover
{
    /*border-top: 2px solid #ffaa00;
    padding-bottom: 3px;*/
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    background-color: QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:1 #212121, stop:0.4 #343434, stop:0.2 #343434, stop:0.1 #ffaa00);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked, QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #323232;
    border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked
{
    background-color: qradialgradient(
        cx: 0.5, cy: 0.5,
        fx: 0.5, fy: 0.5,
        radius: 1.0,
        stop: 0.25 #ffaa00,
        stop: 0.3 #323232
    );
}

QCheckBox::indicator{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #323232;
    border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
}

QRadioButton::indicator
{
    border-radius: 6px;
}

QRadioButton::indicator:hover, QCheckBox::indicator:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #ffaa00;
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
   image:url(:/images/checkbox.png);
}


QCheckBox::indicator:disabled, QRadioButton::indicator:disabled
{
    border: 1px solid #444;
}

QSlider::groove:horizontal {
border: 1px solid #bbb;
background: white;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #bbf);
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #ffbc6d, stop: 1 #d7801a);
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #eee, stop:1 #ccc);
border: 1px solid #777;
width: 13px;
margin-top: -2px;
margin-bottom: -2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #fff, stop:1 #ddd);
border: 1px solid #444;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal:disabled {
background: #bbb;
border-color: #999;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal:disabled {
background: #eee;
border-color: #999;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:disabled {
background: #eee;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-radius: 4px;
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>326</width>
     <height>52</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>Parameter</string>
   </property>
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <property name="sizeConstraint">
     <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="wordWrap">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QSlider" name="horizontalSlider">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="invertedAppearance">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
      <property name="wordWrap">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>50</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

ParamBlock.h:

```
#ifndef PARAMBLOCK_H
#define PARAMBLOCK_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class ParamBlock;
}

class ParamBlock : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ParamBlock(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void changeTitle(QString X);
    void changeMin(int X);
    void changeMax(int X);
    void setValue(int X);
    ~ParamBlock();

private slots:

    void on_lineEdit_textEdited(const QString &arg1);

    void on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value);

private:
    Ui::ParamBlock *ui;
};

#endif // PARAMBLOCK_H
```

What I would like to get is that either the scrollarea does what it is supposed to do (make me scroll through it if it doesnt fit instead of overlapping everything) or properly resize the widgets.

I tried lots of stuff with the SizePolicies but that didnt work out. I also tried a QGridLayout without succes (same result).

Using Qt Creator 3.5.0 with Qt 5.5.0 on windows 7 32 bit.

Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: first of all, you could also use a QGridLayout instead of vboxlayouts in hboxlayouts. :-)

Comment: I started with a QGridLayout. That gave the same result as I'm having now, I'll give it a shot again though.

Comment: It's just a recommendation. I don't think it will change the behavior regarding the size of the items in it. It's just easier to write and read.

Comment: you need to update the sizes of your widgets (VERY IMPORTANT! see that your widgets (the scrollbars) have the same size but their space isn't as big as before) and the contentmargins of your vlayouts and hlayouts when you change the size of the windows. Check when you are changing it and make a connect so it updates that sizes :)

Comment: Qt does it by itself if you choose the right design.

Comment: Your problem **was** in the `.ui` file! See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the lack of top-level layout in `ParamBlock`. There's a layout in the group box, but none in the underlying widget itself. Once you set it, it'll all work.

Here's how a minimum free-standing implementation of `ParamBlock` might look like.

Note the use of `QLabel::setNum`, `qBound`, holding members by value (not by pointer), lack of hardcoded sizes, leveraging of mutual updates, error checking and use of modern syntax.

```
class ParamBlock : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(int min READ min WRITE setMin)
   Q_PROPERTY(int max READ max WRITE setMax)
   Q_PROPERTY(int value READ value WRITE setValue USER true)
   QHBoxLayout top { this };
   QGroupBox box;
   QHBoxLayout layout { &box };
   QSlider slider;
   QLabel minLabel, maxLabel;
   QLineEdit edit;
   void on_edit_textEdited(const QString & text) {
      bool ok;
      auto value = text.toInt(&ok);
      if (!ok) return;
      auto newValue = qBound(slider.minimum(), value, slider.maximum());
      slider.setValue(newValue);
   }
   void on_slider_valueChanged(int value) {
      edit.setText(QString::number(value));
   }
   bool event(QEvent * ev) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      if (ev->type() == QEvent::FontChange) fontChangeEvent();
      return QWidget::event(ev);
   }
   void fontChangeEvent() {
      QFontMetrics fm { font() };
      edit.setFixedWidth(edit.minimumSizeHint().width() +
                         fm.width(QString(edit.maxLength()-1, QLatin1Char('0'))));
   }
public:
   ParamBlock(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
      top.addWidget(&box);
      top.setMargin(0);
      layout.addWidget(&minLabel);
      layout.addWidget(&slider);
      layout.addWidget(&maxLabel);
      layout.addWidget(&edit);
      slider.setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
      slider.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
      edit.setMaxLength(3);
      edit.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
      connect(&edit, &QLineEdit::textEdited, this, &ParamBlock::on_edit_textEdited);
      connect(&slider, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, &ParamBlock::on_slider_valueChanged);
      fontChangeEvent();
      setMin(min());
      setMax(max());
   }
   int min() const { return slider.minimum(); }
   int max() const { return slider.maximum(); }
   int value() const { return slider.value(); }
   void setMin(int min) {
      minLabel.setNum(min);
      slider.setMinimum(min);
   }
   void setMax(int max) {
      maxLabel.setNum(max);
      slider.setMaximum(max);
   }
   void setValue(int val) {
      slider.setValue(val);
   }
   void setTitle(const QString & title) {
      box.setTitle(title);
   }
};
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something small I missed. Thank you!

Comment: @BenNon Sometimes, that's what you get for using `.ui` files for simple widgets. I've included an example of how you might implement that widget in a minimum amount of code.

Comment: @Kuba Trying to understand the code, in the 6th (and 8th) line `QHBoxLayout top { this };` is that any different from `QHBoxLayout top;` Or is it just a non-standard way to 'comment' the intended parent. Also is all this in a header `.h` file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example that solves your Problem:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  QMainWindow* mainWindow = new QMainWindow(0);
  QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea(mainWindow);
  mainWindow->setCentralWidget( scrollArea );
  QWidget* widget = new QWidget( mainWindow );
  QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout( widget );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
      QPushButton* button = new QPushButton( 
        QString("Row %1 Col %2").arg(i).arg(j), mainWindow );
      gridLayout->addWidget( button, i, j );
    }
  }
  scrollArea->setWidget( widget );
  mainWindow->show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `mainWindow` as an argument to the push button. You don't need a mainwindow at all, in fact. Just because a Qt Creator template has it, doesn't mean you need it. It's silly. Everyone uses a `QMainWindow` when in fact in 90% of cases they don't.

Comment: I don't think you solve anything since you don't use the OP's `ParamBlock` widget... and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: compile the code in a single main file, it does work.

Comment: @ Kuba Ober: I do know that i don't need a QMainWindow, but why should I not use one? The fact I use a QMainWindow has nothing to do with the fact it works and nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Don't use one because: it makes it appear necessary; upholds the mainwindow cult; it is noise. In this example, every use of `new` is unnecessary, as is the use of `QMainWindow`. I mean, you claim it's minimal - I then give you counterexamples to show that it is *not* minimal :) You can also replace all the includes with `#include <QtWidgets>`.